# AlertDialog without its stock background

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

This is what I have tried with:

```
    public AlertDialogEx(final Context context, View lytCustom)
    {
        // Set your theme here
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // This is the layout XML file that describes your Dialog layout
        this.setView(lytCustom);
//        this.setContentView(lytCustom);
    }
```

and it does not get rid of that black background:

[image]

Using `setContentView()` instead of `setView()` throws the infamous "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" message, for no obvious reasons unfortunately. How can I achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define background of your dialog in xml layout file/
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?windowBackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >
.........................
body of your dialog
...........................
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can do this programaticaly

```
  view.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with a regular fullscreen Activity instead of the AlertDialog that uses the theme @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar, and has lots of transparent background.